# Uncaught Reference Error: init is not defined

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers

I am getting the above error on my HTML file @ line number 22. I tried several attempts and was unable to resolve it.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Web-Map</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,minimal-ui">
        <!-- loading the stylesheet for the application -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <!-- loading the style fro the OpenLayers --> <!-- versions of OpenLayers can be downloaded from the OpenLayers website --><!-- this is version 2 of OpenLayers being used  -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="OpenLayers/theme/default/style.css"/>
        <!-- loading the OpenLayers javaScript file -->
        <script src="OpenLayers/OpenLayers.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <!-- the div holding the map -->
        <div id="map">
            <!-- loading the javaScript file containing the properties of the map -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="web-map.js"></script>
        </div>
        </script>
    <head>
```

The .js code looks like this

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
/*specifying the extent of the map*/
var extents = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508, -20037508, 20037508, 20037508.34); 

/*loading various controls to the map*/
var control, controls = [];

   var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map" /*this map is the div id in the html code*/, {
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ArgParser(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'div':OpenLayers.Util.getElement('dropdown-content')}),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
            //new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.Zoom(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
        ],
        maxExtent: extents,
        minExtent: "auto",
        restrictedExtent: extents /*one cannot pan outside the specified extent*/
    },
        {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")}, /*specifying the projection*/
        //{displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")},
        //maxResolution: 156543.0339,
        {units: 'm'},
        {allOverlays: true} /*all other data added will overlay on the basemap*/
        );
function init (){
 //var google_sat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite",{type:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,numZoomLevels:40});

 var OSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");  /*loading the OSM basemap*/


/*loading the overlays from GeoServer.web_map is the workspace name. Loading the layer as a WMS*/

  var Boundary = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Boundary",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {layers:":Boundary",transparent: true, EPSG:4326, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: true},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);



 var Ext = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Ext",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {layers:":Ext",transparent: true, EPSG:4326, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: false},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);



 var Erv = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Zonning",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {layers:":Erv",transparent: true, EPSG:4326, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: false},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);



 var Parcels = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Parcels",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms",
        {layers:":Parcels",transparent: true, EPSG:4326, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: false},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);



/*adding the data to the map object*/ 

map.addLayers([OSM,Boundary,Ext,Erv,Parcels,]);

/*specifying the center of the map and a zoom level of 3*/
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(15.7832786675738,-22.0109820763529),3);

var zoom = 5;
        //var map;
        var infoControls;
        var highlightlayer;
        var aktLayer=-1;
        // pink tile avoidance
        OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 5;
        // make OL compute scale according to WMS spec
        OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH = 25.4 / 0.28;


        infoControls = {
            click: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Karibib/wms',
                title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                layers: [Boundary,Ext_Boundaries,Erv,Parcels],
                queryVisible: true,
                infoFormat:'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
                eventListeners: {
                    getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            "chicken",
                            map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                            null,
                            GenPopText(event),
                            null,
                            true
                        ));
                }}
            }),
            hover: new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
                title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                layers: [Boundary,Ext,Erv,Parcels],
                hover: true,
                // defining a custom format options here
                formatOptions: {
                    typeName: 'water_bodies',
                    featureNS: 'http://www.openplans.org/topp'
                },
                queryVisible: true,
                infoFormat:'text/html'
                })

            };

            for (var i in infoControls) {
                infoControls[i].events.register("getfeatureinfo", this, showInfo);
                map.addControl(infoControls[i]);
            }

            infoControls.click.activate();
            //infoControls.hover.activate();

            // Active layer combo
            populateLayer(0);
        }
        }

        // sets the HTML provided into the nodelist element
        function setHTML(response){
            document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = response.responseText;
        };

        function errorHTML(response)
        {
            alert("req erro:" + response.responseText);
        }

        function showInfo(evt) {
            if (evt.features && evt.features.length) {

                 highlightLayer.destroyFeatures();
                 highlightLayer.addFeatures(evt.features);
                 highlightLayer.redraw();

                 $('nodelist').innerHTML = GenPopText(evt);

            } else {
                $('nodelist').innerHTML = evt.text;
            }
        }

        function GenPopText(evt){
                 var temstr="<b><i>" + evt.features[0].gml.featureType + "</i></b><br/>";
                 for(var key in evt.features[0].attributes)
                 {
                    temstr += "<b>" + key + "</b>:" + evt.features[0].attributes[key] + "<br/>";
                 }
                 return temstr
        };
```

Comment: You call in the HTML a function **init()** that doesn't exist in your JS: <body onLoad="init()">

Comment: You need to define this function: **function populateLayer(e){ ...write your function here ... }**

Comment: I found the source where your code is coming from: https://khayer.wordpress.com/category/gis/openlayer/. Unluckily function definition for `populatelayer` is also missing there. Just comment it out or delete this line.

Comment: Yes, that is right, I did comment it out and nothing happens. My map is showing perfectly, the layers and can zoom in and out. I have integrated the get feature info code by Khayer, configured the proxy in Geoserver and nothing happens when I click on the map?

Comment: I have updated the code, managed to resolve the init error through this code piece (main code updated), I am a starter, please advise if that will work with the get feature info code i have </div>
  </script>
   <body onload='init();'>
    <div id='map_element' style='width: 99%px; height: 652px;'>
 <div id='input_wrapper' style='position:absolute; left:610px;
top:0;'>
    </div>
     </body>
</html>

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using really old version of OpenLayers? If you are using it just to learn OpenLayers, it's complete waste of time. Current version is 6.0.1 and is very, very different from the one you are using.

Comment: Since I am a beginner, it is advised that one starts with Openlayers two, easy to understand and there are alot of documentation and developers who can assist. I tried Openlayers 4 last year and it was complicated and could not get all desired functionality.

Comment: That is very bad advice! As I wrote, API's of newer versions are really completely different than in 2.x. Whatever you'll learn about OpenLayers in version 2.x will be completely useless and misleading in newer versions.

Comment: Noted. For now, I would like to solve the wms getfeature info on a popup in Openlayers 2 then I can take up new versions in the future. Perhaps you can assist with previous questions? thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I've ever used only 5.x versions of OpenLayers and so I can't help you here.